# android custom intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

We have an app that starts an activity for SENDTO with the intention of letting the user send an email. the choice of all the various email apps is fine, but we'd like to give the user of bypassing that step in the future ... e.g., add a "remember this decision" button at the bottom of the chooser. from then on, we'd launch that specific activity instead of getting the chooser.

I'm wondering if we can interact with the built-in create chooser functionality at a lower level to affect this. If not, could someone point / post some code snippets for this? I suppose the trick is understanding how to get a list of activities that can handle the intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen a lot of questions about modifying the app chooser, and they all seem to state that no, you cannot change the built-in app chooser, but you can create a custom app chooser using `queryIntentActivities()` in the `PackageManager` class.

Comment: thanks, and this post helped as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name. you can rip a lot of code from the android stock chooser impl.