# In share option in dialog box, I want to add my custom intent option

Tags: android

I am using this code to share link in android app.

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject test");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "extra text that you want to put");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share via"));
```

But i want to add cutom intent option in dialoag box.

If i have twitter and facebook app in my phone, then above code give me share option
1) Twitter 
2) Facebook
3) Bluetooth(if phn supported)

Also with this I want to add

4) Commnets (on  comments click user will go my Comment activity)

I want to make share like this.
Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make your Comment activity respond to that intent

Comment: @njzk2 Can you explain, what code need to change in above code ???

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a chooser. It contains all intents that reply to ACTION_SEND text/plain.

To have your comment activity in that list, you need make an intent-filter in your manifest matching that actions for your comment Activity.

Alternatively (and moreeasily, too), if you don't want your Comment activity to respond to external ACTION_SEND text/plain, you can use the response given to this question : [Custom filtering of intent chooser based on installed Android package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name) : Add a Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS extra to the intent.