# Android. Custom Intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I wonder, is there any way to choose behavior using `Intent.createChooser` method?
For example, I have an image, which I would like send by e-mail, if it's chosen (first option). And on second option I'd like to send `sms` with the link on this image 
(For which I'll need complex actions - upload image to the sever, retrieve download link, which I'd like to be in the `sms` and paste it to the `sms`)

Could you possibly come up with any suggestion, what should I do to accomplish the second task?

I believe I can send an e-mail with image with something like this:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("application/image");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{textMail}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Some Subj"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some Extra Text"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileUri));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

**UPD:** I realized, that what I truly needed is to intercept the user click, if the `sms` was chosen in intent chooser. So, the question is how it might be accomplished?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15022153/909497  Hope this helps.

Comment: @ACengiz, thank you, but I have no difficulty with sending an e-mail. The question is how to get Chooser for both - sms and e-mail. Difference between them is that I want to send e-mail with the image itself and sms with the link to the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1)Create Intent to perform share or send operation,

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"velmurugan@androidtoppers.com"});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hi");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi,This is Test");

email.setType("text/plain");
```

2)Create AlertDialog to set the Application in the alertdialog,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Custom_chooser.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
WMLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
dialog.show();
```

3)Get the list of application related to the particular intent using the ResolveInfo

```
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(email, 0);
Collections.sort(launchables,newResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
```

4))Set the list of application to the custom listview.

```
adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

5)Finally,lanch the particular application when choose the application from the list of application in listview,

```
ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
activity.name);
email.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
email.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
email.setComponent(name);
startActivity(email);
```

For more refer this link:http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2014/01/custom-chooser-android-in-example.html

Comment: This answer references variables that aren't declared. What's `pm`, and how does the reader create it? Why does the `AppAdapter` need `pm` in its constructor?

Comment: @wsgeorge Appears that the code was adapted from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Introspection/Launchalot/src/com/commonsware/android/launchalot/Launchalot.java.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that it can't be accomplished exactly as I wanted.

Possible way is to build custom app chooser using queryIntentActivities() in the PackageManager class. 
Helpful post: [Custom filtering of intent chooser based on installed Android package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name)

Another possible way is to create custom pop-up - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu 

 or floating context menu - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu

It appeared to be that what customer actually wanted was only some custom `Dialog`. Something like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("E-mail / MMS").setItems(R.array.send_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
            // of the selected item
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25217145/5448389).
You could also add a control for Facebook, as Facebook does not work well with the sharer:

```
if (activity.applicationInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("facebook")) {
                    //Share on Facebook
                    ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().
                            setContentUrl(Uri.parse(mLink)).
                            setImageUrl(Uri.parse(mImageURL)).
                                    setContentTitle(mTitle).
                                    setContentDescription(mDescription)
                            .build();
                    com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.show(mActivity, content);
                } else {
                    //Share on selected application
                    ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                            activity.name);
                    shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                    mActivity.startActivity(shareIntent);
                }
```