# Application chooser to open specific file type - dialog interface

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing a file manager for Android and want to display a list of possible applications to open files depending on their type.  I have this working already using the following:

```
    String mimeType = DocumentFileHelper.GetMimeType(asset.file.getName());
Uri mediaContentUri = Uri.fromFile(asset.file);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(mediaContentUri, mimeType).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mediaContentUri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION), "View"));
```

I would like however to use the version that is more if a dialog-type interface.  I've seen this dialog-type version in other apps (IE ES File Explorer) so I know it's out there, I'm just not sure how to expose it.

the method I'm using above just splits the screen and shows available applications for the given file type at the bottom half of the screen.  It does the job, it's just kind of clunky.

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to call (the intent I presume) that is more of a modal dialog type interface?

TIA

Comment: What is in the upper half?

Comment: That's the built in one.  If you saw another one, it was either a phone specific override by the OEM, or something the app made itself.

Comment: Why do you use createChooser()?

Comment: @GabeSechan I see. Any suggestions on putting me on the right path to create a custom one for my app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298048/android-custom-intent-chooser

Comment: @GabeSechan wow!  that looks like it exactly!  thanks so much man.  If you wanna dump that into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.