# Display sharingIntent as a list, not a grid

Tags: android, list, android-intent, share

I would like to display a sharing intent as list like this:

[image: list]

but in my case it is displayed like this and i don't want this:

[image: grid]

After looking many posts, i am unable to find how to do it.

Help welcome.

my code:

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

```
    String shareBody = "https://google.com";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"google");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share"));
```

Comment: Take a look at the answers in this post...perhaps one can help you get the desired interface:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298048/android-custom-intent-chooser

Comment: Thank you Barns. So, 30 lines of code to get a list instead of a grid? 
Is there not a simpliest way to do it?
A bit heavy no?