# Share my app via specific apps only

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, share

I want to create a sharing button via some applications only.
right now I`m using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Name");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this cool app http://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.yourpackagename");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Tell a friend about App Name");
startActivity(chooser);
```

But it opens a huge window with all the apps installed at the device. I want to show only chosen options (Facebook, Whatsapp, Gmail).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer, I would suggest going with it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755553/1542720

Some other workarounds/solutions :

http://hkdevtips.blogspot.in/2013/02/customize-your-actionchooser-intent.html

[Custom filtering of intent chooser based on installed Android package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name)