# Android share intent for multiple apps at same time?

Tags: android, android-sharing

Is it possible to select multiple apps at the same time for sharing content using Android share functionality ?

**Update**

From the comments figured out that going about implementing custom chooser intent would one option. Found these two urls which explain about creating custom chooser.

[Custom Intent Chooser example 1](http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2014/01/custom-chooser-android-in-example.html)

[Custom Intent Chooser example 2](http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.in/2012/01/creating-custom-android-intent-chooser.html)

Wondering if I can implement multiple select/checkbox in the custom chooser and what would the action be.

Comment: I think you must handle that by self, get all app that has capability for sharing or anything else, show one dialog for user with multiple choice, then send your data to selected app by intent

Comment: Not really. Each app handles a share intent in their own way.  Most of which requires user intervention (adding a caption and tagging a facebook photo for example).  It wouldn't make sense to do this.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Thanks. Any pointers on how to create custom share functionality ? Resources which I can refer to ?

Comment: Most services have an API available that you can hook in to.  Just search for "Facebook API", "Instagram API", "Google+ API", etc.  There's a lot of documentation for each.

Comment: @DeeV Thanks. Lets say if its text we're sharing, then we set it only once in the share intent and then choose one of the apps available. I was wondering if there was some way I can choose multiple apps at this point.

Comment: Not using the native sharing mechanism.  I'm pretty sure if you set multiple explicit actions, it'll just open the first app it finds.

Comment: if you want send text message you can search and find many sample code and tutorial, see http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html for starting. other step that i'v said must be done by simple code, search about those, if you had problem with one of them ask us,

Comment: @DeeV Yeah. Thats true. Unless I figure out a way to post in background without opening up the apps and then schedule posting to each app one after the other.

I'd say its almost equal work as using individual sdk itself. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Yes. I've seen the sample code for sharing text. I was wondering if you can do it for multiple apps at the same time.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name for getting application that can send text message, you must show this list and continue with selected item