# Creating custom chooser for share intent by package name

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I have a Text in my android activity and I want give the user option to share it on social apps like whatsapp, line, facebook, twitter etc.

But I want to create a custom chooser so that it won't show unintended apps in the chooser.

I'm aware of this snippet

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

How can I make it so that in the chooser it'd only show the apps which I can specify by their package names.

Thanks

Comment: Seems it is not possible :

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name

Answer (score 0):

Even though I think this question is duplicated, but since I can't find the duplicated question yet, let me provide an answer first.

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent shareInent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareInent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareInent, 0);
// put the name of the packages you want in this ArrayList
ArrayList<String> wantedPackage = new ArrayList<>();

if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShare.setType("text/plain");
        String infoPackageName = info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase();

        if (wantedPackage.contains(infoPackageName)) {
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "put your text here");
            targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
            resPackageNames.add(infoPackageName);
        }
    }
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Chooser title");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```