# Android share intent Twitter: How to share only by Tweet or Direct Message?

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, share

I need to share an image via only Tweet.

Here is my code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        if (mInsertableToGallery) {
            mInsertableToGallery = false;
            mInsertedImagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mShareImage,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + System.currentTimeMillis(), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        }
        // share only 5 specific apps:
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        if (!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfos) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShareIntent.setType("image/*");
                targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(mInsertedImagePath));
                if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.facebook.katana") //fb
                ||TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.instagram.android") //instagram
                ||TextUtils.equals(packageName, "jp.naver.line.android") //line
                ||TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.google.android.apps.plus") // plus
                ||TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.twitter.android")) // twitter
            {
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
            }

            }
        }
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "");
        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivity(chooser);
```

and I get the result:
[image: share only via 5 apps]

When click "Android System", Twitter share popup:
[image: share Twitter]

What I want:

1. How to share via Twitter only by Tweet or Direct Message ?
2. How to change title & icon of share item. Ex Twitter share item from "Android System" to "Tweet"?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Surprised that there's not more upvotes. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get it done :(

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't manage to get both Tweet and Direct Message to the front but the following code will get you either one there. Actually you can get both to the front but both appears with same name "Tweet" so its kind of unusable.
I have also included facebook, insta and tumblr.
To get Direct Message in place of tweet replace `com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity` with `com.twitter.android.DMActivity`. To get both add another ' if ' for DMActivity.

Can't say surely but I don't think you can change the Icon of the package for your app.

```
List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");//("text/plain");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            if(TextUtils.equals(packageName,"com.facebook.katana")|TextUtils.equals(packageName,"com.instagram.android")
                    |TextUtils.equals(packageName,"com.tumblr")) {
                targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
            }
            if(TextUtils.equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.name,"com.twitter.android.composer.ComposerActivity")) {
                targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                targetedShareIntent.setClassName(
                        resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
                        resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
            }
        }
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For composing new Tweet:

```
public static Intent getTwitterShareIntent(Context context) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android",
            "com.twitter.composer.ComposerShareActivity");
    return shareIntent;
}
```