# How to track data from android play store if user installed from invite link

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-invites

I am using Firebase deep-linking for content sharing in my android app and it working perfectly. Now I want to use Firebase App invite to invite friends to download and signup on my app. Now I have some problems.

1) Firebase App invite provides only two way to invite friends (SMS and Email). But I also want to share with WhatsApp, FB etc.

2) If above case not possible then if I am using deep-linking with the custom parameter with App play store link then how to get those parameters on the app first launch after installing from play store?

Please suggest.

Comment: did you try it with that intent param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Firebase App invite provides only two way to invite friends (SMS
>   and Email). But I also want to share with WhatsApp, FB etc.

yes, it's possible to share via whatsApp, fb etc, Actually once you generate the link you can create your own share intent and share that link, you can create the links manually also refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links)

> 2) If above case not possible then if I am using deep-linking with the
>   custom parameter with App play store link then how to get those
>   parameters on the app first launch after installing from play store?

use pendingDynamicLinkData that you get in your callback to get the those custom parameters you set.

```
 FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
//get your properties here
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
```

you can [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics) it even after a while too as a second option. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics

Comment: 1) I know I can create own share intent but Firebase app invite provides only two option SMS or email.Check firebase documentation: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/)
And here is code to for app invite action :

2) This is exactly I am using right now for deep-linking. But my question is how to get those parameters after app installed from play store. Because play store doesn't pass those parameters on the app first open.

Comment: yes it does, as an out of the box solution and the reason is because of this https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/best-practices check out  Build a custom share sheet section in that link

Comment: can you post where you are inserting those params

Comment: Yes you are right, we can build a custom sheet section for other channels but I don't know how to create and launch that sheet with this code:
   ` private void onInviteClicked() {
        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Invite friends")
                .setMessage("samdlkknaslkdnlas")
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com"))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent,4);
    }`

Comment: this link talks about it https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/grow/get-referrals-firebase-invites.html using this key EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS you can find more info here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name/8550043#8550043 refer this on how to do the above

Comment: Thank u for your suggestions. My problem is solved already by using deep-linking. Previously I had a doubt that maybe play store doesn't return deep-links query parameters but now I have tested and it does. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: sure, glad i could help happy coding

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (but not perfect) using the user's IP address. Note I'm not familiar enough with firebase to know whether you could use firebase for this instead of your own server:

1. Configure a page on your own website so that it:

   1. Reads and stores the URL parameters (e.g. "source=facebook&invite=123") and the user's IP.
   2. Redirects the user to Google Play.
2. Configure the android app to query or update your website upon first launch.

When your app is launched, the user's IP address will be sent back to your server. Your website now knows that it was *probably* the user with that invite code who launched the app.

Of course there are cases where users share IP addresses (e.g. office workers going through the same router), but this is the best solution I've been able to come up with so far.