# How to exclude an app from Intent Createchooser in Android

Tags: android-intent, package, waze

I want to know how to exclude app from intent createchooser 
I have the code without the exclude and the package name
. Please help. Bellow is the code:

the package is "com.waze".

```
            String uri = "geo:0,0?q=" + "address";
            Uri u = Uri.parse(uri);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,u);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose Navigation Software"));
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name