# Android Intent Chooser - populate list of apps by package names

Tags: android, android-intent

I know that I can launch another app by knowing its package name by doing something like this:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.yourapp");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

However, I would like to open up a `chooser` with a list of apps that are known by their package names. These apps don't fall under the typical intent categories, like `ACTION_SEND`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to this: [Custom filtering of intent chooser based on installed Android package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734678/custom-filtering-of-intent-chooser-based-on-installed-android-package-name).

Check the answer from pleonasmik.

Hope that helps!