# How to open chooser intent of whats app and gmail only to send an attachment document in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I need to send the document created from my app to only gmail and whatsapp.

for whatsapp I got the working code,

```
        val filelocation = GlobalVariables.getMyFilePath(this, "dummy_file.mem")
        val uri = Uri.parse(filelocation.absolutePath)
        val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        whatsappIntent.type = "text/plain"
        whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
        whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "members file list")
        whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        this.startActivity(whatsappIntent)
```

based on this I just follwed the same for gmail. but the is not getting attached. it toast message `file not attached`

```
        val email = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        email.setPackage("com.google.android.gm")
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf<String>("vikas16acharya@gmail.com"))
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "members file list")
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        email.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        email.type = "message/rfc822"

        this.startActivity(email)
```

- how to send attachment to gmail
- how to show only `whatsapp` and `gmail` in chooser intent action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***how to send attachment to gmail ?***

To send files you need some more things,

first Inside `Manifest`->`application` add the below snippet

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

then create a folder `xml` under `res` and add this file

`file_provider_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

then on your code add below line instead of `val uri = Uri.parse(filelocation.absolutePath)`

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", filelocation)
```

Now you can send attachments.

***how to show only whatsapp and gmail in chooser intent action ?***

refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550043/8750174